# How do iterate between my core data depending to find entities with a particular value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm a beginner to swift. I have a coredata entity named Task with an attribute Date. I want to iterate between all nsmanaged objects in this entity and extract the one with a particular date and put them in an array.

```
func loadTasks(){
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" // assigning the date format
    let now = df.string(from: Date()) // extracting the date with the given format
    let appDel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext// handler to access the core date database by using the context from the app delegate        loadTasks()
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Tasks")
    
    do {
      coreTasks = try context.fetch(request) as! [NSManagedObject]
        for item in coreTasks {
            for date in item.value(forKey: "date"){
                if (date == now) {
                    todaysTasks.append(date)
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

I tried this but i'm getting syntax error all over the place.

Comment: Please paste the errors in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues

Replace

```
for item in request {
   for date in item.value(forKey: "date") {
       if (date == now) {
```

with

```
for item in coreTasks {
   if item.value(forKey: "date") as! String == now {
```

---

A better syntax is to `filter` the records

```
func loadTasks(){
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    df.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" // assigning the date format
    let now = df.string(from: Date()) // extracting the date with the given format
    let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext// handler to access the core date database by using the context from the app delegate        loadTasks()
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Tasks>(entityName: "Tasks")
    
    do {
      coreTasks = try context.fetch(request)
      let todayItems = coreTasks.filter{$0.date == now}
      todaysTasks.append(contentsOf: todayItems)

    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Still better is to apply a predicate

```
func loadTasks(){
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    df.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" // assigning the date format
    let now = df.string(from: Date()) // extracting the date with the given format
    let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext// handler to access the core date database by using the context from the app delegate        loadTasks()
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Tasks>(entityName: "Tasks")
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date == %@", now)

    do {
      todaysTasks = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

And name Core Data entities always in singular form (`Task`).

Comment: Thank you i did that. for date in item.value(forKey: "date"). this line is giving me an error now. "For-in loop requires 'Any?' to conform to 'Sequence'; did you mean to unwrap optional?"

Comment: You have to cast the type, please read my answer carefully. And don't use `value(forKey `anyway. Use the *better syntax*.