# what is the best way to condition a tableview data and row count depending on a particular attribute from an array of NSManagedObject

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have an array of nsmanagedobject with a date attribute. I'm trying to make my table view load only the objects that have an attribute of date of today. what's the best way to do set the number of rows and set the cells based on a property from any nsmanagedobject array. I can work around it with multiple arrays but that will make my code such a message especially with my contextual actions. any help or tip is appreciated :) I have multiple tableviews inside one tableview controller and I have one array to populate them with.

Comment: I gave you a efficient solution to filter the dates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62661366/how-do-iterate-between-my-core-data-depending-to-find-entities-with-a-particular. And if you take my advice to use dot notation rather than `value(forKey` you get rid of the type cast errors.

Comment: the iteration works but I have to story my values in another array. which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I updated the answer in your previous question with a solution to filter the items while fetching the data. And be aware that your string date format is not sortable. Consider to use `yyyy-MM-dd`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Another way to do this, which based on your code, might most likely not be the optimal way to do this is to use a filter function such as follows:

First, add this function to a Date extension:

```
extension Date {
   func isSameDate(_ comparisonDate: Date) -> Bool {
        let order = Calendar.current.compare(self, to: comparisonDate, toGranularity: .day)
        return order == .orderedSame
    }
}
```

Then filter your existing array (keep in mind that unless you store that filtered array, you will be filtering multiple times - inside numberOfRows and cellForRow at):

```
let todaysItems = items.filter{ $0.isSameDate(Date()) }
```

---

You can do that by simply creating a function:

```
func loadTodaysItems() -> [Item] {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
    let startDate = Date().startOfDay
    let endDate = Date().endOfDay
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date != nil AND date >= %@ AND date <= %@", startDate as NSDate, endDate as NSDate)
    /// (Optional) if you want to sort items by date
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]
    
    do {
        return try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching data from context: \(error)")
    }
    return []
}
```

Also, make sure you add this extension:

```
 extension Date {   
    var startOfDay: Date {
        return Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)
    }
    
    var endOfDay: Date {
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.day = 1
        components.second = -1
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: startOfDay)!
    }
 }
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid making another array. I already have an initial array of NSmanaged object. I just want to apply this condition "if (task.value(forKey: "date") as! String == now)" then it should populate the tableview with the task object that has a date of now which is a "dd-MM-yyyy" format

Comment: Typically, this is the best way to do it. The other way to do it using your existing array, is to use a filter function. However, keep in mind that if you are going to filter more than once or twice, it can get needlessly expensive. I'll update my answer with the other option and you can choose which fits your code best.

Comment: could you briefly explain what this function does? if i understood it correctly it takes an array fitlers it out accordingly and return an array right?

Comment: Sure. The filter function, as its name indicates, filters an array based on some condition. For example, in this specific case, it will filter out your items array and only keep the items dated today. Another example would be, if you want to filter an array of optionals and only keep non optional values, you would go like this: array.filter{ $0 != nil }. Note that $0 stands for the first parameter of the closure (in this case the element of the array filter), $1 is the second parameter (if applicable), and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution won't work because according to the OP's previous questions the `date` attribute is `String`